# How to add a delay with JQuery? (make it wait 5s before continue)

Tags: javascript

being specific:

- I have a code that needs to run after 5 seconds
- That code is inside a function
- That function gets called several times by an other function already inside a setTimeout()

what happens is that on the first time it runs ok... but on the next runs it doesn't wait those 5 seconds!

the code looks like this:

```
//==================== create variables: ====================

var x = 0;

//==================== create functions: ====================

function wait5s() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
    }, 5000);
    x++;
}

function repeat5times(){
    while (x<5) {
    wait5s()
    }
}


//==================== run this: ====================

alert("Click Ok and Wait 10 seconds for next alert!");
setTimeout(function() {
    repeat5times();
}, 5000);
```

this code is not my original code, but the problem is the same:
- x gets incremented to 5 BEFORE the alerts pop up! Then they pop up all one after the other!
i tried to put the `x++;` inside the setTimeout inside wait5s()... but the browser stops responding! :(

i want a 5 seconds delay between each alert!

so, what am i doing wrong? :\
thanks in advance ;)

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with jquery. It is plain and simple javascript. Please remove jquery from your question and from the tags.

Comment: jquery is great but it is [not the tool for everything](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: What i intended was a way to do it with JQuery... since i couldn't do it with raw js... turns out my logic was wrong!

Thanks for the comment btw! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
function repeat5times(){
    while (x<5) {
        wait5s()
    }
}
```

just sets 5 setTimeouts all for the same time.  If you want it to run every 5 seconds for 5 times, then you need to code it differently.  You could either use `setInterval()` or set a new `setTimeout()` when the first one fires or you could set 5 timeouts each with a different time interval.

Here's one method that calls `setTimeout()` for the next iteration when the previous one finishes:

```
function repeat5times() {
    var cntr = 0;

    function run() {
        if (cntr < 5) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                ++cntr;
                console.log("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
                run();
            }, 5000);        
        }
    }

    run();
}
```

Here's another method using `setInterval`:

```
function repeat5times() {
    var cntr = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
        ++cntr;
        if (cntr >= 5) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Here's a method using variable setTimeouts:

```
function waitNs(sec) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
    }, sec * 1000);
}

function repeat5times() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        waitNs(i * 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... i solved the issue by replacing the while with an if, to get out of it, and calling the function every time a need it to run again!
;)

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` is an async function which does not block your wait5s method call.
Therefore, you endup setting timeout 5 times right one after another which puts the alert invocation functions in the timeout queue to be invoked after 5 seconds immediately one after another.

What you need is, to call next wait5s after first timeout function is invoked.

```
function wait5s(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {

        alert("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");

        x++;
        if(callback){
            callback();
        }

    }, 5000);
}

function repeat5times() {

    var callback = function () {
        if (x < 5) {
            wait5s(callback);
        }
    };

    wait5s(callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick... i'm still getting the logic of it, but it worked perfectly! ;)

Comment: you could read about asynchronous javascript programming on net.

Comment: the use of callback is nice & i was slow to answer but if i may using `var repeat5times=setTimeout //...` seems (to me) an elegant shortcut @JosEvora

Comment: @mikakun setTimeout returns a handle to the timer which is a number and not a function reference. So, your code would give error. probably you meant assigning the function reference which is passed to setTimeout.

Comment: no i meant that, i was wrong , I mixed it all up with setInterval (using a global to clear the interval)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to have the x inside the`setTimeout`'s function in order for x++ to be triggered every 5seconds.
2. You are calling `wait5s()`; continuously before x is 5. Calling it continuously starts 5 setTimeOut functions and that's why 5 seconds later they pop up one after the other:

   ```
   while (x<5) {
      wait5s()
   }
   ```

It is like having :

```
   setTimeout(function() { alert("go after 5sec");}, 5000);
   setTimeout(function() { alert("go after 5sec");}, 5000);
   setTimeout(function() { alert("go after 5sec");}, 5000);
   setTimeout(function() { alert("go after 5sec");}, 5000);
   setTimeout(function() { alert("go after 5sec");}, 5000);
```

These are the reasons why it didn't work the way you expected it to work.

One solution is to have `wait5s();` in an if statement inside the `setTimeout`'s function.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 5alerts at the same time,  try this code

```
var x = 0;
var t=0;

//==================== create functions: ====================

function wait5s() { 
   t+=5000;
    setTimeout(function() { 
         alert("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
     },t);
   x++;
}

function repeat5times(){ 
while (x<5) { wait5s() } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in simpler terms if first call should execute after 5 sec, so for second function call it needs to be after 10 sec. similarly third should be after 15 sec

```
//==================== create variables: ====================

var x = 1;

//==================== create functions: ====================

function wait5s(myVariable) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("alert # " + x + "\nNext alert will pop up in 5 seconds now!");
    }, myVariable * 5000);

}

function repeat5times(){
    while (x<=5) {
       wait5s(x)
       x++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are really looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) rather than `setTimeout`.

```
 function myAlert() {
     alert('Next alert in 5 secs');
 }

 var si = setInterval(myAlert, 5000)
```

Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to stop timer.